# What encryption algorithm does GNU recutils use?

Tags: encryption, gnu

> Recutils offers a way to encrypt specified fields in a record, whilst leaving the rest in clear text. -- [GNU Recutils Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/manual/Editing-Records.html#Editing-Records)

What encryption algorithm does it use by default?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/manual/), the section on [confidential fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/manual/Confidential-Fields.html) mentions that the only restrictions imposed on the encryption algorithm used is that it be a symmetric cipher (i.e. password-based/shared-key-based rather than public-key-based), and that the encrypted data is converted to some ASCII form via e.g. base64 encoding.

Looking at [the project's `configure.ac` file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/recutils.git/tree/configure.ac#n109), we see that it contains code for detecting the `libgcrypt` library.  If the library can not be found on the host compiling the code, GNU recutils will be built without support for encryption/decryption of fields.

[The `libgcrypt` library](https://www.gnupg.org/software/libgcrypt/index.html) is a general purpose cryptographic library that is part of the GnuPG software project. It has [a number of](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/Symmetric-cryptography.html) symmetric ciphers.